# How to use FILTER function in excel to to exclude certain values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-filter

First, this is becoming very difficult for me to explain, so please bear with me. I want to make it easier to calculate for a puzzle (killer sudokus basically).
So I made an excel table for all possible permutations possible with 1 to 9, their sum, and their number of digits. Now I am trying to use the Filter function (I don't want to mess with the table now) to give me all results that use a particular no. of digits, have a particular sum, and exclude certain digits.

The process till now:
I made all the permutations with all the different digits laid out in different columns. Then I made a no. of digits column (ranging from 2 to 8). Then I made a sum column. Then I made a concatenate column to make it easier to look at (along with commas). Now my table is ready.

Using the filter function, I was able to get values based on no. of digits and sum, but I am not able to work out how to exclude certain digits.

The code I have used

```
`FILTER(Table14,(Table14[no of digits]=Sheet4!B1)*(Table14[sum]=Sheet4!B4),"not found")`
```

As you can see, this is not working because I have to choose only the correct combinations by inputting in sheet 4.

`So instead of '*' I used + in the 1 to 9 columns, not the 'sum' and 'no of digits' columns but that gave me all the values.`

As an e.g.
no. of digits is 4
sum is 20
what are all the possible combinations?

1, 2, 8, 9

1, 3, 7, 9

1, 4, 6, 9

1, 4, 7, 8

1, 5, 6, 8

2, 3, 6, 9

2, 3, 7, 8

2, 4, 5, 9

2, 4, 6, 8

2, 5, 6, 7

3, 4, 5, 8

3, 4, 6, 7

but I now how do I get it to exclude all combinations with the value 6, leaving me with:

1, 2, 8, 9

1, 3, 7, 9

1, 4, 7, 8

2, 3, 7, 8

2, 4, 5, 9

3, 4, 5, 8

and how do I do it for multiple values, say I don't want either a 6 or an 8.

1, 3, 7, 9

2, 4, 5, 9

The main table contains the following columns

[image]

In a different sheet I input the sum, the number of digits and the digits to exclude.

I am having trouble with the last part, (digits to exclude). How do I do that? I know it can be done with the filtering in the table itself by checking on blanks for the digits I don't want, but I want to get it in a different sheet and table altogether.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest of formulas, but I would consider adding a helper column to your table that you could hide. This column would contain a formula to highlight which combination contain a 6 or an 8.  See the image as a possible exaple.

[image]

I hope this gives you some ideas.
Brad

Comment: I did it. I used your formula and made some changes to fit my needs. The final formula reads something like this:
=IF([@sequence]<>"",IF((IFERROR(FIND(IF(AF$2<>"",AF$2,0),[@sequence],1),0)+IFERROR(FIND(IF(AG$2<>"",AG$2,0),[@sequence],1),0))>1,"Exclude","Ok"),"") 
there are nine of those iferror ones. It took me quite some time to fit the IF in the FIND. I wonder why FIND did not work in IF? Anyway, thank you. Though I am still hoping for there to be a much cleaner solution. Also, another person on another website gave this
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"9",""),"1","")))=LEN(A1)